# Israeli doing melacha on yom tov sheini outside Israel to avoid loss

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, leniencies, parnassah-livelihood

I know that the Mishna Berura says that it is Assur for a Ben E"Y to do Melacha even in private, however I was wondering if anyone knows of a source to be meikal in a case where it can damage Parnassah.

E.g. Someone who works online from home for an Israeli company, is abroad for Pesach and is expected to work first day Chol Hamoed (second day yom tov).

Without getting into the question of working on Chol Hamoed generally, are there valid grounds to be meikal and to work behind closed doors?

Comment: If this applies to you or someone you know, you should be sure to check with your rabbi to see if any proposed leniency applies in that case.

Comment: Why should this be any different than someone working for a nonJewish company in a different timezone and Shabbos? Also, how would the question differ for a Ben Chutz L'Aretz working for an Israeli company.?

Comment: It's very different, the question is  essentially about doing melacha in chutz l'aretz on second yom tov.